# How to Sync network driver folder with document library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any way to sync a document library folder with a network driver folder? so that any changes in either the library or the network driver folder will be available on the other side?

Is there an existing software that can do this? Better, if it can be run on the background instead of having to manually start it every time.

Comment: FWIW, You can connect to a document library via WebDAV, just connect a new network location, and enter the URL of that document library to get it to stay on your computer, or you can open the library via "Open with Explorer"

Comment: @Mike, could you give more details in a answer? what do you mean "connect a new network location"? the author asked to sync a network folder with a SharePoint, so, the files are NOT on the local computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can map a SharePoint location as a drive letter quite simply.

For example from a Windows computer:

1) Press Windows key and type CMD (select to run command prompt)

2) In the Command Prompt window, you can map a drive letter using the following command:
NET USE * http://sharepoint.server.com/site/library

This will map an available drive letter to the SharePoint site or library referenced by the URL.

Type NET USE /? if you wish to see other mapping options. For example you may want to include account credentials, and you may wish to include /PERSISTENT:YES which would ensure that this drive mapping persists over machine reboot.

You can then use any synchronization tools (including ones not designed specifically for SharePoint) as you are now simply ensuring a sync takes place between two accessible drive locations.

There are also some applications that support synchronization from SharePoint to drives including Colligo Briefcase https://www.colligo.com/products/sharepoint/colligo-briefcase-for-windows/

Comment: in my case I need to sync "\\some-computer\folder\my-network-folder" with "https://mygroup.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/my-sharepoint-folder"

Answer (score 1):

Map your Sharepoint to hard drive or meke sure you can access it via UNC.Use sync tool like [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) to sync.

Read the blog to understand it.

http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/02/12/use-skydrive-pro-as-a-sharepoint-content-replicator/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's against the rules - please delete it if it is -

We are thinking of buying avepoint's connector to easily integrate our file servers to sharepoint.
https://www.avepoint.com/products/sharepoint-infrastructure-management/sharepoint-integration/